# Cypher: Create a relationship chain among newly created nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am creating event nodes to track history of changes in my application. There is one action that can create multiple nodes at the same time. I want to be able to create the event nodes and create the relationships between them but I am struggling to get the query syntax correct.

Here is some sample data:

```
CREATE (user:User)-[:LATEST]->(e0:Event)<-[:LATEST]-(pg:Pg),(A:Record)-[:IDENTIFIER]->(A1:Identifier),(B:Record)-[:IDENTIFIER]->(B1:Identifier),(C:Record)-[:IDENTIFIER]->(C1:Identifier)
```

[image]
Lets assume that records A (195), B (197) and C (199) are just created. The latest event before these were created is e0 (193). The end result that I want to achieve is for a new event to be created for A1, B1, C1. The LATEST relationships also need to be updated.
[image]

For the query I have the ids or the user, pg and the records (A, B and C). My query so far has included:

```
START record = node(195, 197, 199), user = node(192), pg=node(194)
MATCH record-[:IDENTIFIER]->identifier
WITH collect(identifier) as identifiers, user, pg
FOREACH (i in identifiers |
  CREATE UNIQUE (event:Event)
  , event-[:EVENT]->i
  , user-[:LATEST]->i
  , pg-[:LATEST]->i
  MATCH user-[r1:LATEST]->(e1) WHERE id(e1) <> id(event)
  MATCH pg-[r2:LATEST]->(e2) WHERE id(e2) <> id(event)
  CREATE UNIQUE event-[:NEXT_USER]->e1
  CREATE UNIQUE event-[:NEXT_PG]->e2
  DELETE r1, r2)
```

This doesn't work because of the MATCH inside the FOREACH. The only option I can think of is to create the events and return the ids. Then do a separate query for each id returned. But this doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Thanks for any help you can provide.